# How to receive .zip file in Flask from Angular UI?

Tags: python-3.x, angular, http, flask, post

I have an Angular application in which I used

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChanged($event)">
```

to upload a `.zip` file. 
I get the file like this:

```
fileChanged(e) {
this.file = e.target.files[0];
}
```

Now, I want to send this `.zip` file to my server `(Python-Flask)` and want to store it as a `.zip` file on my `server-side`.
I send the request to server like this:

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('files', this.file, this.file.name);
fd.append('fileType', 'zip');
this.http.post('/my_app_route1/', this.file, 
          {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/zip'}}).subscribe(f => {
                           ....});
```

To receive and save this, I do the following on my python side.

```
@app.route('/my_app_route1/', methods=['POST'])
    mydata = (request.get_data())
    with open('hello.zip', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(mydata)
```

Now, this data is binary data which I do not know how to write to a `.zip` file from `Python`.
When I try to print "mydata", I see glimpses of my original .zip file data which I had sent from front end mixed with other symbols.

Am I passing the `.zip` file right? If not how should I pass it?
Also, how can I save the `.zip` on my `server-side` using `Python-Flask?`
NOTE: The `.zip` file consists of `multiple directories` and `sub-directories`, and I want to replicate the same on my `server-side`.